# Cannot use keyboard navigation on different navigation tabs

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav, keyboard-shortcuts

1. Enable keyboards shortcuts and the new navigation feature
2. <kbd>G</kbd>o to the <kbd>H</kbd>omepage of Stack Overflow
3. Observe that <kbd>J</kbd> and <kbd>K</kbd> work when selecting questions
4. Change <kbd>T</kbd>abs to your <kbd>2</kbd>nd tab (take any of the defaults tabs *voted*, *active*, etc.)

   This throws the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: StackExchange.helpers.bindShowMoreHotNetworkQuestions is not a function`
5. Observe that <kbd>J</kbd> and <kbd>K</kbd> no longer work when selecting questions on this new tab

Comment: I use keyboard navigation *all the time*, but can't reproduce this. What browser and OS are you seeing this on? What URL did you have loaded in T2? Did a reload correct the error?

Comment: Also, what are the 'different tabs' you talk about, *browser* tabs or *site navigation* tabs? Do you have the [new navigation system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256814/new-navigation-for-stack-overflow-is-in-alpha-testing) enabled?

Comment: They are the tabs of the new nav, that's also why I added those tags

Comment: Reproduced. Good thing I never switch navigation tabs then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this. This has been fixed!